# Laravel: Apply addSelect after groupBy

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables, `milestone_logs` and `milestones`. `milestones` table contains `name` for all milestones. `milestone_logs` has columns `listing_id`, `previous_milestone_id`, `milestone_id` and `closed_type`. This table keeps the information about latest milestone changes for listings. Each listing can have multiple milestone change records. I need to create a query to get the number of listings that moved from each milestone to closed-lost, which means `milestone_id` must be 9 and `closed_type` must be 2. I need only the recent record for each listing. I created this query:

```
DB::table('milestone_logs')
->join('milestones', function ($join) {
    $join->on('milestones.id', '=', 'milestone_logs.previous_milestone_id');
})
->whereDate('milestone_logs.created_at','>', now()->subYear())
->where('previous_milestone_id', '!=', 9)
->whereNotNull('previous_milestone_id')
->where('closed_type', 2)
->select(DB::raw('listing_id, MAX(milestone_logs.created_at) as latest_date'))
->groupBy('listing_id')->orderBy('latest_date', 'desc')
->get();
```

This is the result

[image]

Everything is correct but now I need to also get a `name` column value from the same row as `latest_date`. Then I can calculate the quantity of how many times the distinct listings moved to closed milestone. I tried to add the column name to select like this, but it returns an error about nonaggregated column:

```
->select(DB::raw('listing_id, name, MAX(milestone_logs.created_at) as latest_date'))
```

If I add an aggregate function, it works, but it's clear that the returned data is not valid.

```
->select(DB::raw('listing_id, MAX(name), MAX(milestone_logs.created_at) as latest_date'))
```

I also tried to include an `addSelect` function after `groupBy`, but this does not help either:

```
->addSelect(['name' =>
    Milestone::selectRaw('name')
        ->whereColumn('id', 'milestone_logs.previous_milestone_id'),
])
```

I need the result to look like this:

[image]

But the first record here has an incorrect milestone name, because of `MAX(name) as name`. Please note, I don't want to change the sql mode and I don't want to send multiple queries because of performance issues. Is there any other solution for my problem? All I need is to include a milestone name from the same row as `latest_date`

Comment: Please show the generated SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, which does the job, but **BETTER ANSWERS ARE WELCOME**

I used `CONCAT` function to merge 2 columns in my current `select` like so:

```
->select(DB::raw("listing_id, MAX(CONCAT(milestone_logs.created_at, '|', name)) as name, MAX(milestone_logs.created_at) as latest_date"))
```

Note, that I added a separator `'|'`. Then I can use `map()` function to transform the concatenated columns into just a milestone name:

```
$milestoneLogs = $milestoneLogs->map(function($item) {
    $item->name = explode("|", $item->name)[1]; 
    return $item; 
});
```

This gives me the exact result I wanted